# How can I composer package on the server that I have installed on my local machine?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Via Terminal I installed the Ramsey/Uuid plugin:

```
composer require ramsey/uuid
```

In my PagesRepository.php I am creating this function:

```
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

  function generateUid()
  {
     $uuid = Uuid::uuid4();
     $uuid = $uuid->getHex();
     $uuid =  substr($uuid,0,10);

     return   $uuid;
  }
```

I am using the function in my PagesController.php

```
  $unique_id = PagesRepository::generateUid();
  $entity->setUnique_id($unique_id);
```

It is working very fine on my local machine, but then I push it via git to my server and there I get the error message:

> Attempted to load class "Uuid" from namespace "Ramsey\Uuid". Did you
>   forget a "use" statement for
>   "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Uuid"?

I cannot install anything on the server because it is a shared host and the permission is denied so I copied the `ramsey` folder into my vendor folder on the server. But this was not solving the problem.

I do not understand, why this is asking for the Symfony validator, as it does not need it on the local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of `composer` auto generated files not linking your folder or class (`ramsey`) .

So, as i understand you can not run `composer update` or `composer install` on shared hosting, you should upload whole updated `vendor` folder to your server.

Then auto generated files like `vendor\composer\autoload_psr4.php` will be updated and have link to class like `Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid`.

Point is

> PHP Namespace can not include class/file automatically. It loads classes with composer's auto generated linking files and __auload magic function.

Comment: It worked when I deleted the whole vendor folder and uploaded it!

Answer (score 3):

If you are not running `composer install` in your server, you need to copy the whole `vendor` folder, at least, to wherever you are running the system.

The package you have installed might have installed other dependencies, for example, but you are not copying them when transferring only the files for that package. And at the very least you'll need the generated autoloader files.

Since you creating the installation on dev and transferring it to production, I would advise delete your local `vendor` folder and re-do the whole installation first:

```
composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-scripts --no-progress --no-suggest --classmap-authoritative --no-interaction
```

And transfer **that** vendor folder to production. You should make sure that the installation process doesn't include any other step (enabling bundles, creating configuration files, etc), but I'm hoping you took care of that at some point.

After yo do that, you can reset the previous steps, and do a regular `composer install` for development.